# Are sets with at most one point collinear?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

In Euclidean geometry, every set with $2$ points is collinear. My question is, are singleton sets and the empty set also collinear? I think it depends on the exact definition of collinear.

Comment: (i) As you say, it depends on the definition (like all of mathematics! :). (ii) In my experience, the term _collinear_ means _lying on some line_, but in practice is never used except for sets containing more than one point, in which case a functionally equivalent definition would be _lying on a unique line_. If you ask me, _yes_ singletons are technically collinear. (iii) In the hope it sheds light, _coplanar_ similarly means _lying in some plane_. Thus, collinear points are coplanar; I don't recall ever seeing _coplanar_ used to mean "there is a unique plane containing the points."

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I don't think _collinearity_ implies a unique common line, either. Suppose some construction produces three collinear points, similarly to the intersections of opposite sides of a hexagon inscribed in a conic (Pascal's theorem). Suppose then you can choose an initial setup for the construction so that the resulting three points coincide. Would we say they are no longer collinear? OK, strictly speaking, we get only one point then, just three times. But would anybody make an exception like 'the three resulting points are collinear _except_ when they coincide'...?